# Google API Drive: Upload files using node.js but, How use the 1TB storage of a workspace account and not the 15GB of service account used to auth?

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, google-drive-api, workspace

I've developed a process on my server using Node.js for uploading several files to a google drive account.

1. First at all, I bought additional storage (1 TB) in my Google workspace account for having enough space. Let's call the Google account **user.account@domain.com**
2. Then, I've created a service account under **user.account@domain.com** and all credentials needed for authentication from node.js.
3. I've added the service id account with a Domain wide delegation for impersonation process.
4. I've defined all scopes supposed needed:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```

5. And finally, I've added to JavaScript implementation all supposed needed too. The next code is only declaration of auth Google API from JavaScript implementation:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');

// service account key file from Google Cloud console.
const KEYFILEPATH = 'upload-files-server-to-drive-7a5e1bf2dcbe.json';

// Request full drive access.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata'];

// Create a service account initialize with the service account key file and scope needed
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KEYFILEPATH,
    scopes: SCOPES
});

auth.subject = 'user.account@domain.com';

const driveService = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

module.exports = {
    driveService
}
```

6. The next function is inside a module and here is where the uploads occurs:

```
const upload = async ( params ) => new Promise (async ( resolve, reject ) => {
    const driveService = params.driveService;

    const fileMetadata = {
        'name': `${params.id_numero}${params.name}`,
        'parents':  [  params.parentId  ]
    };
    
    try {
        if (fs.existsSync(params.folder + params.name)) {
            //file exists
        }else{
            reject({
                result: "error",
                message:"El archivo no existe. No se puede subir nada. " 
            })
            return
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        reject({
            result: "error",
            message: "Hubo un error" . err 
        })
        return
    }

    // Definición del archivo que se desea subir
    const  media = {
        mimeType: params.mimeType,
        body: fs.createReadStream(params.folder + params.name)
    };
    await driveService.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: 'id'
    })
    .then( response => {
        console.log(response)
        switch(response.status){
            case 200:
                let file = response.result;
                resolve({
                    result: "success",
                    message:'Created File Id: ' +  response.data.id,
                    url : "http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+response.data.id,
                    id : response.data.id
                })
                break;
            default:
                console.error('Error creating the file, ' + response.errors);
                reject({
                    result: "error",
                    message:"Error al crear el archivo en Drive, " + response.errors
                })
                break;
        }
    })
    .catch( e => {
        console.log(e)
        reject({
            result: "error",
            message:"ERROR. No se puede acceder a DRIVE " ,
            error : e.errors
        })
        return
    })
})
```

The code above definitively works for uploading files to drive. However, although even **user.account@domain.com** has enough space (100% free of 1TB) all uploaded files still being uploaded on the service account default storage, which one is only 15GB.

What am I missing for setting to upload on the desired storage?

Thanks for any help!

Documentation and references: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Google API scopes: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#auth

Comment: Are you able to see the uploaded files in the Drive web UI? I ask this because if you don't then you are probably not doing the impersonation correctly and the information is being uploaded to the service account instead. The service accounts have a 15 GB limit as well, so that would explain the behavior.

Comment: Actually I don't see any impersonation being done in the coding provided, so that is the problem, the files are most likely being managed with the service account instead of the user account.

Comment: @FernandoLara thank you for your answer.  In response about your question if I see files uploades on UI Web, is  Yes, I do.  Furthermore,  the file's owner is the service account user. And I am sure the storage used is the 15GB default you mentioned because once I drop it the service account for creating a new one, all files were deleted too. I am gonna check the second comment you did about missing impersonation right coding. Thanks again.

Comment: Then that is the problem. The service account has a limit of 15 GB storage. The storage can not be increased or changed in any way. Service accounts are also not part of your domain as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#:~:text=Service%20accounts%20do%20not%20belong,own%20or%20manage%20these%20assets), so any benefits from your Google Workspace account does not apply. In this case what you need to do is to use the service account to impersonate the specific user that has the extra storage and upload the files to the drive storage of that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the impersonation you could try:

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './service.json',
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts',...
    ],
    clientOptions: {
      subject: 'email@email.com'
    },
  });
```

You would need to edit it depending on your code and what you are doing.

Comment: your answer was 100% useful.
I only had to add ClientOptions you mentioned.  Great!

Comment: I confirm, the impersonation was succesful. I've uploaded more than 30GB on  user account drive storage. Wonderful help. Thanks